# Mapview showing only google logo at bottom android

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am loading Mapview Programmatically in Activity. But getting the only White screen with Google Logo at the bottom. If I use MapFragement in XML file than Map is loading so my API key is right but at Mapview, showing a white screen.

This is MainActivity code in OnCreate Method:

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.map_container);
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
options.camera(new CameraPosition(new LatLng(0, 0), 1, 0, 0));
mapView = new MapView(this, options) ;
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
linearLayout.addView(mapView);
this.setContentView(linearLayout);
mapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

This is my AndroidMenifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.apps.neonmapbox">

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MapActivity" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="My API Key"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

I follow some of the questions on Stack Overflow but couldn't get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **enable** your map api on **Google Developer Console** under dashboard menu and then re-generate your api key then use it..

It will help you

Comment: I already enable map api on Google Developer Console. It is working with MapFragment. Not working on with Mapview